# java creating double linked lists

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm looking for a way of implementing the class with functionality of a double linked list nodes. I don't want to re-invent the wheel but I DON'T see anything suitable in the standard java library, and I couldn't find an answer on this site.

What I need is to have an array of objects, where each object has a knowledge of its neighbors: like the private class Note in the standard `java.util.LinkedList`.

Few notes here:

1)I CAN'T use `java.util.LinkedList` because the stored objects don't have the links to the neighbours.

2)I CAN'T use `java.util.LinkedList` ListIterator - first of all, I don't want to iterate though all list to find the object, and I don't wan't to keep the object index anywhere - because this will break the program integrity.And I can't keep the Iterator anywhere for the same reason.

What I need is a list of objects with the ability of insertion/deletion,
and also when I pass the objects around, I need to be able for the code to access object neighbors (previous/next).

I assume Java library don't have this? And if I'm going to implement this myself its getting worse.

3)I can't create the base Node class which will be extended by my own class to be listed. My derived class  IS NOT a node, this will break java paradigm of inheritance.

4)I can't create the Node interface because it can't have mutable members ("prev" and "next")

Comment: *")I can't create the base Node class"* - why? You question is confusing, you might want to look at rewording or otherwise clarifying it.

Comment: Too much information. Not clear what your real question is.

Comment: domdom, the java paradigm is that 'extending'  some "Node" class is only allowed if the class IS A "Node". My existing class  IS NOT a Node. Making it a Node will prevent deriving it from other base classes. And make code harder to support.

Comment: tak3shi - the real question is: Does stardard java library have "Doubly linked list "? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list, note that the java.util.LinkedList - is not a real linked list, because Node interface is not exposed

Answer (score 0):

If you want your class to be able to see the nodes "next to each other", you can always give your class it's own variables prev and next and define the methods for insertion.

```
public class MyClass {
    public MyClass prev;
    public MyClass next;
    // Using string as an example for data
    String data;

    public void insert(MyClass myclass, String insert_after) {
        // will depend if you want it sorted or not
    }

    public void delete(String delete) {
        // itterate through recursively to find the node with
        // next.data equal to remove then replace next with next.next
    }
}
```

Please note this was typed on mobile (@ 5am), feel free to comment about errors.

Comment: The adding 'prev' and 'next' will work of course. The only problem is that this is not a general solution. This is what's called  reinventing  a wheel. I would need to implement my own list  with all methods, which of course would be error prone, and I would need to cut & paste this code to different classes, which need the same functionality

Comment: Then couldn't you just create a Node class which implements all that functionality and then use generics to allow it to be reusable, because these methods aren't that complex to implement. I know it might not be a instant solution but beats searching everywhere for something pre-made.